# Undefined index php ajuda

Tags: php

Boas pessoal estou a fazer um teste de php e deu me um erro que nao estou a conseguir resolver este é o teste: [image: teste]

e aqui esta o meu trabalho o erro e na linha 22[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vc iniciou a sessão dentro da função mas não fez a chamada dela, logo `$_SESSION['x']` não existe.

Comment: Utilize uma condição `if..else` ou *ternário* para verificar se o valor existe, antes de imprimi-lo. Ex.: `echo isset($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['x'] : 'No ecxiste';`

Comment: Inclua o código ao invés das imagens

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esse problema esta acontecendo porque não há a Session com value 'x' definida. Pelo seu código a session é definida em uma função javascript que nunca é chamada :/. Ou seja se você tentar usar a Session 'x' e ela nao existe provavelmente dará erro de undefined index. E isso você pode tratar com um if antes de exibir, como por exemplo:

```
isset($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['a'] : null;
```

Tenta chamar a função "numerox();" ou por um evento onclick/onchange ou coloque esse trecho após o término da função, só para ver se funciona, caso não funcione, poste o código pra poder ajuda-lo melhor.